# SQL Server: stored procedure performance between UNION ALL of two statements vs ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have been tasked with improving the performance of a stored procedure that uses a `UNION ALL` of two statements to retrieve the desired results. In my travels, I've come across the idea of using `WITH ROLLUP`as an alternative to help performance. I'm decent at SQL, but I think I need a little help with this one. (I'm also new here so I'm not as familiar with the Db as I'd like.)

It is selecting from basically, the same places in both statements as you can see by the joins. But the conditions are a little different between them. One join in the second statement has `<> 'zzzCUSTOM'` but the corresponding first statement doesn't have this, as an example. I think there's a better way to write this so as to not need the `UNION ALL`, maybe by combining the conditions/joins into one statement since it's all adding together (`UNION ALL`) anyway?... Other ideas?

The stored procedure is also built with dynamic SQL so it's a bit hard to follow. Here it is as regular SQL (with all the variables filled in):

```
SELECT 
    [SKU No], [SKN], [Description], [Orders], 
    [Quantity], [Unit Price], [Total Price] 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         1 AS TOT, 
         'Totals:' AS [SKU No], 
         '' AS [SKN], 
         '' AS [DESCRIPTION], 
         isnull(SUM([Orders]), 0) AS [Orders], 
         isnull(SUM([Quantity]), 0) AS [Quantity], 
         isnull(SUM([Unit Price]), 0) AS [Unit Price], 
         isnull(SUM([Total Price]), 0) AS [Total Price] 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              COUNT(distinct o.orderno) AS [Orders], 
              SUM(oi.quantity) as [Quantity], 
              oi.unitprice AS [Unit Price], 
              SUM(oi.extprice) AS [Total Price] 
          FROM
              orderupdates ou  
          INNER JOIN 
              orders o ON o.orderno = ou.orderno 
          INNER JOIN 
              orderdetails od ON od.orderno = o.orderno 
          INNER JOIN 
              orderitems oi ON oi.orderno = o.orderno 
                            AND oi.linenum = od.linenum 
          INNER JOIN 
              items i ON i.itemid = od.itemid 
          WHERE
              actdate >= '2015-05-01' 
              AND ou.actdate < '2015-05-15' 
              AND type = 0 
          GROUP BY
              oi.unitprice, i.skuno, i.description) S 

    union all 

    select 0 AS TOT, 
        isnull(i.skuno,'') as [SKU No], 
        isnull(vi.SKUNo,'')AS [SKN], 
        isnull(i.description,'')AS [DESCRIPTION], 
        count(distinct o.orderno) AS [Orders],  
        isnull(sum(isnull(oi.quantity,0)),0) as [Quantity], 
        isnull(oi.unitprice,0)AS [Unit Price], 
        isnull(sum(isnull(oi.extprice,0)),0)AS [Total Price] 
    from 
        orderupdates as ou  
        inner join orders o  on o.orderno = ou.orderno and o.orderno <> 'ZZZCUSTOM' 
        inner join orderdetails od  on od.orderno = o.orderno 
        inner join orderitems oi  on oi.orderno = o.orderno and oi.linenum = od.linenum 
        inner join items i  on i.itemid = od.itemid 
        inner join vendoritems vi  ON vi.ItemId=i.ItemId 
        left outer join VendorBuyers BORD  on BORD.Buyer = 'admin' and BORD.Usage = 10000 and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO 
    where 
        case when BORD.EMailId is null then 
            case when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 
            when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then 1 
            when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then 1 end 
            else 0 end = 1 
            and O.fgSpecialPO IN (0) 
            and ou.actdate >= '2015-05-01' 
            and ou.actdate < '2015-05-15' 
            and ou.type = 0 
    group by i.skuno, vi.skuno, i.description, oi.unitprice ) T
ORDER BY 
    TOT, [Quantity] DESC, [SKU No]
```

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans (`UNION ALL` vs `WITH ROLLUP`) in SSMS?

Comment: Not yet. Still figuring out HOW to write it to use `WITH ROLLUP`.

Comment: If the total needs to include the ZZZCUSTOM order numbers, shouldn't the list of items include this as well?  Here is a blog entry that has some good information and examples of the WITH ROLLUP command    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/09/21/aggregation-with-rollup.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to use `GROUPING SETS` instead.  This give more flexibility than `ROLLUP`

```
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS (
      (oi.unitprice, i.skuno, i.description),
      (i.skuno, vi.skuno, i.description, oi.unitprice)
    )
```

there will need to be a few extra tweaks, such as a few `ISNULL(A,'') AS A`, etc, buy hopefully this will get you moving in the right direction.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more and some equivalence examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the sub queries first.  In the inner sub query of the top part of the union is going a group by i.description, but the description field is not used in the select statement.  The item table is also referenced in the statement, but is not needed.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct o.orderno) AS [Orders], 
    SUM(oi.quantity) as [Quantity], 
    oi.unitprice AS [Unit Price], 
    SUM(oi.extprice) AS [Total Price] 
FROM
    orderupdates ou  
INNER JOIN 
    orders o ON o.orderno = ou.orderno 
INNER JOIN 
    orderdetails od ON od.orderno = o.orderno 
INNER JOIN 
    orderitems oi ON oi.orderno = o.orderno 
                AND oi.linenum = od.linenum 
--INNER JOIN 
    --items i ON i.itemid = od.itemid 
WHERE
    actdate >= '2015-05-01' 
    AND ou.actdate < '2015-05-15' 
    AND type = 0 
GROUP BY
    oi.unitprice, i.skuno --, i.description
```

There are more optimizations that can be done to your SQL statement.